# Windows Defender SmartScreen and electron app

Tags: electron

I have developed a very simple electron app, which I then packaged using "electron-packager".

I zipped up the application and sent it to my client. When this client runs the application, he gets the "Windows protected your PC" window/warning with "Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.

App:       AppName.exe

Publisher: Unknown publisher

Along with the "Run anyway" and "Don't run" buttons.

The app runs fine when the user clicks on "Run anyway", but understandably he would like to get rid of this warning (and at the very least show the actual Publisher).

**I know about the code-signing certs, so there is no need to go there...**

(**IMPORTANT NOTE**: I haven't asked him to look at the properties of the file to see if Security indicates "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer.". I am going to check that tomorrow and hopefully it just needs to be "Unblocked".)

What I am wondering is, why don't I get this same warning when I run the application on my PC? (We are both running Windows 10.) I have cranked my UAC all the way up to "Always Notify" and I have tried setting "Check apps and files" and "SmartScreen for Microsoft Edge" to "Warn" and even "Block". Still, the application always starts with NO errors or warnings. If I could at least reproduce what he is seeing, I would at least know if/when the code-signing works.

(To be clear, I'm not using an "installer". The client doesn't want one. And, as I said, this is a very SIMPLE application/utility. They want to be able to copy the zip file, unzip the contents and run the app..)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The issue is, that when files are received from the internet, there is a download flag set. This is depending on certain conditions.
I've experienced, that files from local network addresses don't get this flag.

You can find the flag in the File Properties dialog.
When this flag is set, the SmartScreen scans the file and checks, if it can be trusted or not. This is depending on the reputation of the signature used to sign the executable.

Reputation for a certificate is established automatically. If you cannot wait, then you need to use an EV cert.

Comment: What is a EV cert? 

Comment: Extended Validation. It is a special certificate you can buy which is normally only provided via USB-dongle.

Comment: Any idea how many "Run anyway" clicks are required to clear the smartscreen?

Answer (score 3):

hope this works for you.
I use "electron-builder" to build my application and it exports a .exe file then I archive this file by WinRAR app and set it for download.
when the user downloads this file and extracts this file it automatically removes the downloaded flag from the .exe file and the user will not see the warning anymore this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is for the client to "unblock" the zip file before extracting. (Or, I suppose extract it, then unblock the exe....) To reproduce the problem, I just emailed it to myself. :)